# Reading a socket asynchronously with `read` and `epoll`

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll, iocp

There's something I miss when it comes to `epoll`

In Win32, If a socket is registered under some IOCP and no data is available for the socket to read, then issuing an asynchronous read action using `ReadFile` with some overlapped struct will return `false` and the error code is `WSA_IO_PENDING`.

When data *is* available, then the IOCP pulls out the relevant `overlapped`, the buffer given to `ReadFile` contains the newly-read-data and you can continue from there.

When it comes to linux and epoll, I don't get it. If you register a socket under some `epoll` object and no data is available, `read` will just return `-1` and `errno` is `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN`. I also understand that monitoring `EPOLLIN` is semi-helpfull, as `EPOLLIN` talks about being able to read from the socket, not about actual existing data to read.

how can one tell the socket "hey, I want X bytes of data or less to be written this buffer, If you don't have the data now, it's fine - give it to me when you do. notify me when the data is stored in the buffer"?

Is it possible with an `epoll` object as it is possible with IOCP?

Comment: "*notify me*" - How?

Comment: @melpomene in any way. for example, by unblocking the thread stuck on `epoll_wait`, signaling, etc.

Comment: Wait, you have a thread? Why bother with epoll then? Just do a blocking read.

Comment: @melpomene c'mon, be serious.

Comment: I am serious. WTF?

Comment: _`EPOLLIN` talks about being able to read from the socket, not about actual existing data to read_ - `EPOLLIN` means there is data or error in the socket.

Comment: I think you have the workflow on non Windows OSes backwards. Use `epoll` (or `poll()` or `select()` or on BSDs `kqueue`) to see when the socket can be successfully read from without blocking, and then `read()` it. If the polling function doesn't indicate that the socket is readable, don't bother trying to.

Comment: There is a posix asynchronous io api for being notified when an operation completes, but it's poorly supported and a pain to use. The glibc implementation doesn't even use the relevant Linux syscalls; it uses threads to emulate asynch stuff.

Comment: @Shawn aha.. I get it now. wow, I actually prefer the windows approach. If you post you comments as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @melpomene asynchronous-io != io on another thread. read about the 10k problem.

Comment: @DavidHaim It was you who brought up the "unblock a thread stuck in a function call" thing. That's exactly what a blocking read is.

Comment: @melpomene *sigh*. ok.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do that. IOCP implements proactor model, while epoll() -- reactor model. There is a glibc threaded wrapper that imitates proactor (`man aio`), but since it is thread-based, you most likely don't want to use it. There is also "linux aio" (`man io_submit`), but it is supported only for files (not for sockets) and only for some filesystems.

Comment: Have a look at how [asio](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/blob/master/asio/include/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.ipp#L470) does it with `epoll_wait`.

Comment: There’s this article which is a good survey of Linux existing asynchronous IO solutions and echoing your question. Great read: http://davmac.org/davpage/linux/async-io.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API that would notify you when X data is available, or buffer reads for you. There are APIs that will *unblock* when *any* non-zero amount of data is available. One of these APIs is `epoll_wait`. You will need to read and collect X data yourself in your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Linux sockets API which would do what you want - i.e. perform the operation when the socket is available. You will always have to perform the `read` explicitly in the code.

The best you can do is to have a non-blocking IO with `poll` multiplexing, or a blocking IO with a thread per socket.

Comment: as much as I appreciate the answer, I have to disagree and disclaim. IOCP doesn't work by launching the action on another thread. otherwise IOCP is just a lame threadpool. plus, if you don't remember what is the API then there's nothing I can get from your answer. anyway thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHaim there was a typo in my answer - it should have read 'There is **no** Linux socket API...' Sorry for that. As for IOCP mechanism, looks like I was mistaken about it - I will just remove it, it servers no purpose anyways.